# how to teach magit to pass multiple push-options at once

Tags: magit, transient-library

GitLab has a few [push options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html) for which I'd like to create switches in magit-push's transient.

Causing `-n` to add `-oci.skip` is simple enough:

```
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push "-n" '("-s" "skip CI" "-oci.skip"))
```

I would also like that `-m` adds three different options (`-omerge_request.create`, `-omerge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds`, and `-omerge_request.remove_source_branch`).  The following code *fails* to achieve that goal:

```
(transient-append-suffix 'magit-push "-n"
  '("-m" "auto-merge on success" 
    "-omerge_request.create -omerge_request.merge_when_pipeline_succeeds -omerge_request.remove_source_branch"))
```

The above causes the string containing the three options to be passed as a single argument to `git push`. I.e., the spaces are not argument separators, but belong to the argument.

Unfortunately, `git` wants to receive these as three arguments.  I could make three different switches in magit-pull, but that would be cumbersome to use. I'd prefer to have a single switch that activates these three arguments.  How can I do that?

Comment: I suggest asking https://github.com/tarsius directly.